# Null Pointer Exception on MockMvc.perform on @Test class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, spring-restcontroller

I am writing to write a unit test for my RestController (POST) and I am getting a NullPointerException on mvc.perform(...) line.

Here's my RestController :

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyController {

@Autowired
private Service1 service;

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@RequestMapping(value = "/logError", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity ErrorHandlor(@RequestBody JSONStructure jsonStructure) throws Exception{


    service.getDocument(jsonStructure.getID(), jsonStructure.getLog());

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);

   }

}
```

And here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class, 
Service1.class, AppConfig.class})
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
MyController service = new MyController();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(service).build();
}

@Test
public void testController() throws Exception{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/logError";

    JSONStructure structure = new JSONStructure();
    structure.setNumber("num");
    structure.setID("id");
    structure.setLog("log");

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(structure)
    this.mockMvc.perform
    (MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("http://localhost:8080/logError")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(json))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated())
    .andReturn();

}
```

}

I am getting a NPE on line containing this.mockMvc.perform(...).

Can anyone point out what might the problem be?

Comment: use WebApplicationContext instead of directly calling your controller.
I believe that tha mvc in @Before itself is null. Can you debug and verify

Answer (score 0):

You will get it to work in this way (i tested it):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

@SpringBootTest
public class TestControllerImplTest {

@Mock
private TestBO TestBO; //if for example the controller calls some autowired service

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks //i think this was your main problem, you missed this annotation
TestControllerImpl controller;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
}

 @Test()
 void shouldReturnAllTests() throws Exception {
      TestDTO testDTO = new TestDTO();
      testDTO.setId(Long.valueOf(1));

      List<TestDTO> allTests = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(testDTO));

      when(testBO.getAllTests()).thenReturn(allTests);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/test/getAllTests")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());         
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. When using @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), use @Autowired MockMvc mockmvc.
2. When using @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class) or MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) then 
   use this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(service).build();

Don't mix both Spring and Mockito runners.